# No such column error on selection value

Tags: android, android-sqlite

This is the message from LogCat:

> no such column: dkbdxfywpbkb (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT meetup_event_id FROM events WHERE meetup_event_id = dkbdxfywpbkb

Why is it trying to find a column called "dkbdxfywpbkb" when the selection argument is "....WHERE meetup_event_id = dkbdxfywpbkb"

I have checked that column "meetup_event_id" exists and is of type text.

Notes:

- This query works fine except when the value(in this case "dkbdxfywpbkb") I am searching for is a piece of text rather than a number.
- The value(in this case "dkbdxfywpbkb") I am searching for is from the Meetup API and not generated by my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need single quotes.  You want a string constant:

```
SELECT meetup_event_id
FROM events
WHERE meetup_event_id = 'dkbdxfywpbkb';
```

Without the quotes, SQLite thinks the string value is an identifier (numbers are treated differently from strings in this respect).